# SQL Server: Select * from x where (a,b) in (select a,b from z)

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

This does not work in SQL Server:

```
SELECT ID, SQNCNO
FROM JUID AS MID
WHERE 
     (ID, SQNCNO) IN (SELECT NM.ID, NM.SQNCNO
                      FROM JUNM AS NM
                      WHERE (LAST_NAME LIKE 'TESTCASE%')) 
ORDER BY ID, SQNCNO
```

It works in DB2 and Oracle. The problem is `WHERE (ID, SQNCNO)`. Can anyone tell me how I can make this SQL work in SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't currently support tuples with `in`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Exists` is created for this manner

```
SELECT ID, SQNCNO
FROM JUID AS MID
WHERE Exists(SELECT 1 FROM JUNM AS NM
                      WHERE 
                          NM.ID = MID.ID 
                          and NM.SQNCNO = MID.SQNCNO 
                          and (LAST_NAME LIKE 'TESTCASE%')) 
ORDER BY ID, SQNCNO
```

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Server, you have to make two subqueries

```
SELECT ID, SQNCNO
  FROM JUID AS MID
  WHERE (ID IN (SELECT NM.ID
                   FROM JUNM AS NM
                   WHERE (LAST_NAME LIKE 'TESTCASE%')) 
OR -- AND?
SQNCNO IN (SELECT NM.SQNCNO
                   FROM JUNM AS NM
                   WHERE (LAST_NAME LIKE 'TESTCASE%')) 
  ORDER BY ID, SQNCNO
```

Comment: This isn't equivalent to the query in the OP. The comparison needs to be row wise.